# concatinate two String Using pointer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to concatenate two strings using pointer in C, but it doesn't work 100%. At the end of the output String, many unknown characters appear...

```
char* concat_string (char* s1, char* s2) {
    char *s;
    int k=0;
    s=(char *)malloc((strlen(s1)+strlen(s2))*sizeof(char));
    while (*s1!='\0') {
        *(s+k)=*s1;
        k++;
        s1++;
    }
    while (*s2!='\0') {
        *(s+k)=*s2;
        k++;
        s2++;
    }
    return s;
}

int main () {
    char *ch1, *ch2, *s;
    char cch1[10], cch2[10];
    printf("ch1 ?  ");
    scanf("%s",cch1);
    printf("ch2 ?  ");
    scanf("%s",cch2);
    ch1=cch1;
    ch2=cch2;
    s=concat_string(ch1, ch2);
    printf("\n%s + %s = ", ch1, ch2);
    while (*s!='\0') {
        printf("%c", *s);
        s++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is completely unreadable, I think even the compiler can't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not including space for the terminator in the concatenated result. This:

```
s=(char *)malloc((strlen(s1)+strlen(s2))*sizeof(char));
```

should be:

```
s = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
```

You're not *copying* the terminator either, which explains the result you're seeing.

Also, don't cast `malloc()`'s return value in C, and make your input strings `const`.

Your code is very hard to read. The use of an integer indexing variable instead of just using pointers makes it needlessly complicated. For reference, here's how I would write it:

```
char * concat_string(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  char *s = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
  if(s != NULL)
  {
    char *p = s;
    while((*p++ = *s1++) != '\0');
    --p;
    while((*p++ = *s2++) != '\0');
  }
  return s;
}
```

This is of course still somewhat terse, but I'd argue it's more readable than your version.

Comment: You was very fast, I was writing the same and suddenly yours appeared.

Comment: @iharob You know what they say about practice. :)

Answer (score 0):

`printf` expects null terminated strings. Otherwise, it will print whatever characters in memory until it hits one. Your `concat_string` function doesn't put a null terminator on the string.

```
char* concat_string (char* s1, char* s2){char *s;int k=0;
s=(char *)malloc((strlen(s1)+strlen(s2))*sizeof(char));
while(*s1!='\0'){*(s+k)=*s1;k++;s1++; }
while(*s2!='\0'){*(s+k)=*s2;k++;s2++;}
*(s+k) = 0;
return s;
}
```

Also, this function is already written for you, just try using `strcat`.

Comment: You didn't allocate enough space via the `malloc`. So `*(s+k) = 0;` is writing into an invalid memory location. And don't cast the result of `malloc`